# GitHub Webhook Secret Never Validates

Tags: node.js, git, github, cryptography, github-api

I'm using a GitHub webhook to pipe events to an application of mine (an instance of GitHub's Hubot) and it is secured with an sha1 secret.

I'm using the following code to validate hashes on incoming webhooks

```
crypto    = require('crypto')
signature = "sha1=" + crypto.createHmac('sha1', process.env.HUBOT_GITHUB_SECRET).update( new Buffer request.body ).digest('hex')
unless request.headers['x-hub-signature'] is signature
  response.send "Signature not valid"
  return
```

The X-Hub-Signature header passed through in the webhook looks like this

> X-Hub-Signature: sha1=1cffc5d4c77a3f696ecd9c19dbc2575d22ffebd4

I am passing in the key and data accurately as per GitHub's documentation, but the hash always ends up different.

Here is GitHub's documentation.
https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#example

and this is the section which I am most likely misinterpreting

> secret: An optional string that’s passed with the HTTP requests as an X-Hub-Signature header. The value of this header is computed as the HMAC hex digest of the body, using the secret as the key.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 9):

Seems to not work with a Buffer, but JSON.stringify(); Here's my working code:

```
var
  hmac,
  calculatedSignature,
  payload = req.body;

hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', config.github.secret);
hmac.update(JSON.stringify(payload));
calculatedSignature = 'sha1=' + hmac.digest('hex');

if (req.headers['x-hub-signature'] === calculatedSignature) {
  console.log('all good');
} else {
  console.log('not good');
}
```

Comment: Very important to mention that the GitHub hookshot *must* have it's Content-Type set to `application/json`. You will find these settings on the webhook configuration page. https://github.com/MY_ORG/MY_REPO/settings/hooks/HOOK_ID#delivery-response

Comment: Like @MrClean states, use application/json!

Answer (score 6):

Also adding to Patrick's answer, I recommend using Express together with it's body-parser. **Complete example below.** This works with Express 4.x, Node 8.x (latest as of writing).

Please replace `YOUR_WEBHOOK_SECRET_HERE` and do something in `authorizationSuccessful` function.

```
// Imports
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const crypto = require('crypto');

const app = express();
// The GitHub webhook MUST be configured to be sent as "application/json"
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Verification function to check if it is actually GitHub who is POSTing here
const verifyGitHub = (req) => {
  if (!req.headers['user-agent'].includes('GitHub-Hookshot')) {
    return false;
  }
  // Compare their hmac signature to our hmac signature
  // (hmac = hash-based message authentication code)
  const theirSignature = req.headers['x-hub-signature'];
  const payload = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  const secret = 'YOUR_WEBHOOK_SECRET_HERE'; // TODO: Replace me
  const ourSignature = `sha1=${crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).update(payload).digest('hex')}`;
  return crypto.timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(theirSignature), Buffer.from(ourSignature));
};

const notAuthorized = (req, res) => {
  console.log('Someone who is NOT GitHub is calling, redirect them');
  res.redirect(301, '/'); // Redirect to domain root
};

const authorizationSuccessful = () => {
  console.log('GitHub is calling, do something here');
  // TODO: Do something here
};

app.post('*', (req, res) => {
  if (verifyGitHub(req)) {
    // GitHub calling
    authorizationSuccessful();
    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end('Thanks GitHub <3');
  } else {
    // Someone else calling
    notAuthorized(req, res);
  }
});

app.all('*', notAuthorized); // Only webhook requests allowed at this address

app.listen(3000);

console.log('Webhook service running at http://localhost:3000');
```

Comment: Note: Fixed a bug where `req.body` was stringified twice.

Answer (score 5):

Adding to [Patrick's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459329/patrick) answer. It's good to use [crypto.timingSafeEqual](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_timingsafeequal_a_b) for comparing HMAC digests or secret values. Here's how:

```
const blob = JSON.stringify(req.body);  
const hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', process.env.GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET);
const ourSignature = `sha1=${hmac.update(blob).digest('hex')}`;

const theirSignature = req.get('X-Hub-Signature');

const bufferA = Buffer.from(ourSignature, 'utf8');
const bufferB = Buffer.from(theirSignature, 'utf8');

const safe = crypto.timingSafeEqual(bufferA, bufferB);

if (safe) {
  console.log('Valid signature');
} else {
  console.log('Invalid signature');
}
```

To know more about the difference between a secure compare like timingEqual and a simple === check this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095905/whats-the-difference-between-a-secure-compare-and-a-simple/31096242).

[crypto.timingSafeEqual](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_timingsafeequal_a_b) was added in Node.js v6.6.0