# We need to encrypt a product serial number, which has to be decrypted in an App

Tags: android, ios, encryption

We have a physical product with an QRCode, like this:

```
http://example.com/product/[encryptedProductKey]
```

We need to check in an app when the qrcode is scanned if the product key is valid and was made by us.

The qrcode will be lasered onto the product and cannot be changed afterwards.

Unfortunately we are a small startup and noone here really knows about encryption. Is there some kind of dummy approach to this?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't actually need encryption but rather a MAC: Message Authentication Code or a Digital Signature.

If you are both generating and verifying the codes then a MAC is sufficient (I assume this is the case?).

In which case, the product code can be a random set of characters (cryptographically strong random number) and the HMAC (Hash based Message Authentication Code). It could be quite long but would be a simple solution.

The steps would be something like (the below is pseudo code):

1. Generate a strong secret key that you use to generate and verify codes (don't share this)
2. Generate a product code:

code = cryptoRandom(16) // 16 strong random bytes
tag = HMAC(code, secretKey)

3. Encode the key say with Base64
4. Give the resulting base64 string to your customer

To verify the key:

1. Split the decoded product customer key string into the code and tag
2. Generate the tag from the code

   tag = HMAC(code, secretKey)
3. Check that the tag that you generate matches the tag in the customer key

   secureCompare(tag, tagFromCustomer)

Note that you **must** not use `==` to compare the tags as this will be vulnerable to timing attacks. Your language should have a secure compare library. See [What's the difference between a secure compare and a simple ==(=)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31095905/whats-the-difference-between-a-secure-compare-and-a-simple)

As an alternative, if you want to keep the customer key to 32-bytes in length you could take the below approach. However, this would require that you keep a secret key for every customer.

1. Generate a **secret** key for the customer
2. Use that key to generate a customer key by using the HMAC of a zero string (say 16)

   code = HMAC("0000000000000000", customerSecretKey)
3. Give the customer the code

To verify, use the customers secret key to verify

```
secureCompare(customerCode, HMAC("0000000000000000", customerSecretKey))
```

For this to be secure, the customer keys must be **secret** AND **unique**.